# Jython NameError: String - WLST String cast

Tags: jython, wlst

I have imported WLSTModule in Jython and calling:

```
servers = wls.ls("/Clusters/SOA_Cluster/Servers", returnMap='true', returnType='c')
```

having imported wlstModule as wls

This however throws an error of

```
File "/tmp/wlst_module26609970055824621399.py", line 197, in ls
File "/tmp/wlst_module11719639529486505305.py", line 664, in _getList
NameError: String
```

Having gone looked at the underlying line which is `String(child).startsWith("d")`.

I don't think you can actually do a String cast like that?